# python threading issue

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to have the result of my threads in a list.

I have the following sample code:

```
def parallelizer_task(processor,input,callback):
    output = processor(input)
    if callback:
        callback(output)
    return output

class ThreadsParallelizer(Parallelizer):

    def parallelize(self,processors,input=None,callback=None):
        threads = []
        for processor in processors:
            t = threading.Thread(target=parallelizer_task,args=(processor,input,callback))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
        return threads
parallelizer = ThreadsParallelizer
```

But I have the output of threads list as ;

```
* <Thread(Thread-1, started 4418719744)>
* <Thread(Thread-2, started 4425617408)>
* <Thread(Thread-3, started 4429950976)>
```

Is there a way to have the threads result in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for that you can use for example `join`. It will force the main thread to wait until child threads finish the work. You can then store the data in `threading.Thread` objects, something like this:

```
def parallelizer_task(processor,input,callback):
    output = processor(input)
    if callback:
        callback(output)

    # Attach result to current thread
    thread = threading.currentThread()
    thread.result = output


class ThreadsParallelizer(Parallelizer):

    def parallelize(self,processors,input=None,callback=None):
        threads = []
        for processor in processors:
            t = threading.Thread(...)
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()

        # wait for threads to finish
        for th in threads:
            th.join()

        # do something with results
        results = [th.result for th in threads]
        return results
```